# Mysql Query structure for searching two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables sturctured like so:

```
Posts Table
id
content

Meta Table
id
post_id
content
name
```

The posts table is the main parent that can have data from the meta table joined with it

```
Post Table
id   content
1    My first row

Meta Table
id   post_id  content   name
4    1        2011-5-5    date
5    1        My Heading  heading
6    2        2012-3-3    date
7    2        My Title    heading
```

How would I write a query to search for an entry in the posts table that contains meta data content of 2011-5-5 with a name of date and My Heading with a name of heading

I can get them individually

```
Select *
from posts, meta
WHERE post_id = posts.id
   AND (name='date' AND content='2011-5-5')
```

But as soon as I add a second criteria, it returns zero results, becuase we are asking the name field to be two different things

```
Select *
from posts, meta
WHERE post_id = posts.id
   AND (name='date' AND content='2011-5-5') 
   AND (name='heading' AND content='My Heading')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to join to the table twice:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts, meta m1, meta m2
WHERE posts.id=m1.post_id
AND posts.id=m2.post_id
AND m1.name="date" AND m1.content="2011-5-5"
AND m2.name="heading" AND m2.content="My Heading"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :), let me give it a try real quick

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
Select *
from posts, meta, meta meta_2
WHERE (meta.post_id = posts.id
      and meta_2.post_id = posts.id)
   AND ((meta.name='date' AND meta.content='2011-5-5') 
       and (meta_2.name='heading' AND meta_2.content='My Heading'))
```

Since there are two different `meta` records that you want to associate with a single `post` record, you have to select from `meta` twice (once for the 'date' meta-value and once for the 'heading' meta-value).

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to the meta table twice (once for each search) - like this:

```
Select * 
from posts p 
 join meta m_date on m_date.post_id = p.id AND m_date.name='date'
 join meta m_heading on m_heading.post_id = p.id AND m_heading.name='heading'
where
 m_date.content = '2011-5-5' and
 m_heading.content = 'My Heading'
```